# Parse a comma delimited field into seperate fields (MS ACCESS VBA 2003)

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

I inherited a database where user input fields are stored as a comma delimited string. I know. Lame. I want a way to parse these fields in a SELECT query where there are three segments of varying number of characters. Counter to all the recommendations that I insert fields into a new table or create a stored procedure to do this, this is what I came up with. I'm wondering if anyone sees any flaw in doing this as a select query (where I can easily convert from string to parsed and back again as need be).

```
Field_A
5,25,89
```

So to get the left segment, which is the most straightforward:

```
Field_1: Left$([Field_A],InStr([Field_A],",")-1)
```

To get the right-most segment:

```
Field_3: Right$([Field_A],Len([Field_A])-InStrRev([Field_A],","))
```

Middle segment was the trickiest:

```
Field_2: Mid([Field_A],InStr([Field_A],",")+1,InStrRev([Field_A],",")-InStr([Field_A],",")-1)
```

So the result is:

```
Field_1   Field_2   Field_3
5           25        89
```

Any consenting opinions?

Comment: "Counter to **all** the recommendations that I insert fields into a new table ", so why?

Comment: Mostly because I was convinced I COULD do this with a select query rather than making a whole new table. These comma delimited fields are displayed for and entered and updated by the user, but useless to me as a data manager. I wanted to be able to quickly go back and forth with a select query so that I would always have live data as the user is updating. Not that it is a big deal to re-run the maketable, but sometimes they get forgotten when they are a step in multiple nested queries.

Comment: Sounds like you need a form that accepts CSV input from the user but actually stores rational data in a proper table.

Answer (score 6):

Well, if you insist on going down this road......
This might be easier and more adaptable. Create a function in a module:

```
Public Function GetValueFromDelimString(sPackedValue As String, nPos As Long, 
                                        Optional sDelim As String = ",")

Dim sElements() As String

sElements() = Split(sPackedValue, sDelim)
If UBound(sElements) < nPos Then
    GetValueFromDelimString = ""
Else
    GetValueFromDelimString = sElements(nPos)
End If

End Function
```

Now in your query you can get any field in the string like this:
GetValueFromDelimString([MultiValueField],0) AS FirstElement, GetValueFromDelimString([MultiValueField],1) AS SecondElement, etc.

I feel like I am buying beer for a minor, encouraging this type of behavior :)

Comment: Thanks, you are both correct that this is far from ideal. But I have seen people struggling with this issue on many threads and thought I would post this band-aid option that worked as a quick fix for me. The function Peter suggests is much more elegant than my query. Thanks for the added input!

Comment: Nice one Peter!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not asking for information on *how* to parse a comma-delimited field into different fields, but rather looking for people to support you in your decision to do so, yes?

The fact, as you've already discovered, is that you can indeed do this with skillful application of functions in your SQL field definitions.  But that doesn't mean that you *should*.

In the short run, it's an easy way to achieve your goals as data manager, I'll grant you that.  But as a long-term solution it's just adding another layer of complexity to what seems like a poorly-designed database (I know that the latter is not your fault -- I too have inherited my share of "lame" databases).

So I applaud you on "getting the job done" for now, but would advise you to listen to "all the recommendations that you insert fields into a new table" -- they're good recommendations.  It'll take more planning and effort, but in the long run you'll have a better database.  And that will make everything you do with it easier, faster, and more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but someone might search it. You can also do the same strategy as an update query. That way you can keep the original CSV and have 3 new destination fields that can be calculate and recalculated depending on your application purposes.